# uBlock - Remove Mark Zuckerberg from my Facebook display

Tags: firefox, facebook, ublock

Facebook decided that "Mark Zuckerberg" is lonely and suggests that I befriend him on Facebook all the time.

To get rid of that, I would like to remove the useless right column.

I am using Firefox with uBlock plugin.

I tried:

```
! 14/08/2016, 15:00:57 https://www.facebook.com/
www.facebook.com###u_0_0

! 15/08/2016, 21:00:16 https://www.facebook.com/
www.facebook.com###rightCol
```

It has no effect when I reload the page. I suppose Mark is very obsessed with showing up on my screen. Any solution?

[image]

Perhaps instead of removing a `div`—which some nasty JS might observe—one can overlay a div with another opaque white one?

Comment: Might be a better fit on webapps.

Comment: @Hennes He's looking to do browser-level modifications with uBlock on his PC; That seems like SU material to me. :)

Comment: `www.facebook.com###rightCol` works fine here, including after reloading the page. Did you disable cosmetic filtering for the page? See the logger, it will tell you what uBO is doing to the page. It could also be that there is an exception filter in one the filter list you subscribed to.

Comment: @rhill Yes! I had 'cosmetic filtering' enabled; this solved it, please post as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can click the ublock button and click on the little eye dropper to select the element and block it.

[image: uBlock EyeDropper]

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I get a new filter like the one I posted, or if I go into a more inner `div`, for example `www.facebook.com###pagelet_ego_pane` - but __it doesn't work__. Next time I reload FB page, all elements are back, so some JavaScript must be trying to work around the uBlock filters.

Comment: You shouldn't use two adblockers (screenshot) simultaneously: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock#installation